# How to change focus to the next input if I am using components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I need to simulate Tab press by pressing Enter for changing focus from the first Input to second.

I am able to implement this if I am using just basic adjacent inputs, but when using components - I fail. I have the code below on codepen for your comfort https://codepen.io/irvingwash/pen/YoJpYx

```
class Input extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Input'>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onKeyPress={this.props.onKeyPress}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    mimickTabHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            console.log('Pressed');
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                Hello
                <br />
                <Input value='World' onKeyPress={this.mimickTabHandler} />
                <br />
                // This input must be focused
                <Input value='Universe' />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Although its not complete since you still have to handle what to do once it gets to the last input. Hope this helps.

Forked example: https://codepen.io/denz-io/pen/OeBWOe

So we basically just loop through all inputs assuming you had 5 inputs check if the event.target is == to the current item in loop and execute .focus() on input next to it.

```
    mimickTabHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
             let inputsList = Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName("Input"))
             inputsList.forEach((inp, key) => {
                  if (inp == event.target) {
                           inputsList[key + 1].focus();
                  }
             })
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your method right now. About handling what gets after the second input - it's not a problem, because what I've posted here is a very simplified version of the real app, thus I have a specific function for the second input.

Comment: You're weclome I forked your example for convenience hope it helps.